# AMQ8146E: IBM MQ queue manager not available error when using runmqsc

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mq

I am on a Mac Silicon machine, and am getting a `AMQ8146E: IBM MQ queue manager not available` error when I try to use `runmqsc`.

I have installed the MacOS toolkit for MQ from https://ibm.biz/mqdevmacclient and updated PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I have obtained a JSON CCDT.

I have downloaded a qmgrcert_yyyymm.pem file.

I have created the .kdb keystore and imported the queue manager certificate.

I have made sure that `MQSERVER` is *not* set.

I have set and exported `MQCCDTURL` and `MQSSLKEYR`

but when I run

```
runmqsc -c -u mid -w 60 QM1
```

I get the `AMQ8146E` error.

I see this is the queue manager logs -

```
----- amqrmrsa.c : 631 --------------------------------------------------------
03/07/2023 04:03:32 PM - Process(637.10948) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(qm-...............-ibm-mq-0) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.3.1.0) QMgr(QM1)
                    Time(2023-03-07T16:03:32.933Z)
                    RemoteHost(10.74.8.95)
                    ArithInsert1(420)
                    CommentInsert1(CLOUD.ADMIN.SVRCONN)
                    CommentInsert2(gsk_secure_soc_read)
                    CommentInsert3(10-74-8-95 (10.74.8.95))
                   
AMQ9665E: SSL connection closed by remote end of channel 'CLOUD.ADMIN.SVRCONN'.

EXPLANATION:
The SSL or TLS connection was closed by the remote host '10-74-8-95
(10.74.8.95)' during the secure socket handshake. The channel is
'CLOUD.ADMIN.SVRCONN'; in some cases its name cannot be determined and so is
shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Check the remote end of the channel for SSL and TLS errors. Fix them and
restart the channel.
----- amqccisa.c : 12150 ------------------------------------------------------
03/07/2023 04:03:32 PM - Process(637.10948) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(qm-...............-ibm-mq-0) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.3.1.0) QMgr(QM1)
                    Time(2023-03-07T16:03:32.933Z)
                    CommentInsert1(CLOUD.ADMIN.SVRCONN)
                    CommentInsert2(637)
                    CommentInsert3(10.74.8.95)
                   
AMQ9999E: Channel 'CLOUD.ADMIN.SVRCONN' to host '10.74.8.95' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 637 for channel
'CLOUD.ADMIN.SVRCONN' ended abnormally. The host name is '10.74.8.95'; in some
cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide.
```

Comment: What do the queue manger error logs show?

Comment: Is there anything in the client side AMQERR01.LOG?   If not IBM needs to improve the error.   If it was a non mac you would see something like missing cert for channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README says: when running on Apple Silicon processors, the IBM MQ MacOS Toolkit utilises OpenSSL to provide TLS services.

In this case you just need to switch from `.kdb` to `.PEM` format.

If you are working with an MQ on Cloud instance, the default for the certificate download is `.PEM` format. To use `runmqsc` in client mode, you would then export `MQCCDTURL` and `MQSSLKEYR` e.g.,

```
export MQSSLKEYR=<path_to_pem>/qmgrcert_yyyymm.pem
```

Take a look at the `README.Client` file in `/opt/mqm/` for more info on how to convert other certificate types to `.PEM` format.

Comment: Thanks, setting `MQSSLKEYR` directly to the `.pem` worked.